# React-Native: make api call and pass data to child appears as 'undefined'

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make an api call to retrieve some data:

**index.js**

```
const [companyInfo, setCompanyInfo] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
    getCompaniesInfo()
  }, [])

  getCompaniesInfo = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `myURL/${companyID}/settings`,
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}` },
      })
      if (data) {
        setCompanyInfo(data)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

return (
 {componentSelected == 0 && <NewRequest companyInfo={companyInfo} />})
)}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    companyID: state.auth.id,
    user: state.auth,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Parent)
```

**NewRequest.js**

```
const NewRequest= ({ companyInfo }) => {

console.log('companyInfo', companyInfo.time.minuteInterval) // it should print a number, but it says  Cannot read property 'minuteInterval' of undefined

return (
<DatePicker
  minuteInterval={companyInfo.time.minuteInterval}
)
}
```

How can I do to use info that I recover from api in the parent also in the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is NewRequest is receiving an empty object on first render, you can avoid it by doing something like this

```
return (
 {componentSelected == 0 && companyInfo?.time && <NewRequest companyInfo={companyInfo} />})
)}
```

I also suggest that you switch useState({}) to either useState(undefined) or some default values object

that way it will be easier to check for a truthy value before rendering or you could have some values to fall back to if the request fails

Answer (score 1):

This is because `NewRequest` at first render has not yet the result from the API call.

You can add another check when rendering `NewRequest` to make sure it only render when it gets the result from API.

```
 return (
    {
         componentSelected == 0 && companyInfo && companyInfo.time &&
         <NewRequest companyInfo={companyInfo} />
    }
  )
```